# Why Application is not getting deployed in browser while using extjs 4.2?

Tags: javascript, html, extjs4.2

My Application is not getting deployed in Browser.

Listing below the steps, what I used, can someone show me where I went wrong ?

userHome.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>User Home Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">     

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/ext-all.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./ext/ext-all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./ext/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/userHome.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

userHome.js

```
Ext.application({
name : 'extjs-tutorial.com',

launch : function(){

    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', 
    {
        layout : 'fit',

        items : [{
            title : 'First ExtJS Application - Viewport title',
            html : 'Application Viewport area.'
        }]
    });

}
});
```

While running I am getting an empty white Screen in Browser.

I am using ExtJS 4.2.2.

Comment: Press F12 and open developer tools  then check what error are you getting.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/CMPAutomate/ext-theme-classic/ext-theme-classic-all.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
ext-all-debug.js:19838 Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
ext-all.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.fly(...).addCls is not a function
http://localhost:8080/CMPAutomate/ext-theme-classic/ext-theme-classic-all.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). What is the issue here ??

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved. I have added renderTo: Ext.getBody() and also removed ext-all.js from the script section. It worked.

renderTo: Ext.getBody()